# Creating an Observer PHP page for web service events

Tags: php, web-services

I'm using web services in PHP and I need to have an observer page to receive asynchronous event responses from the web services that I call.

For example I make a call using the PHP soapclient like:

```
$soapclient = new soapclient("<URL to the web service>");
$resonse = $soapclient->method1(array[],retunURL);
```

Now method1 only starts a monitor and on generation of any event, the returnURL will be called.

According to the web service documentation, this has to be an "Observer" URL. I'm not sure what observer URL/page means.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post some code snippets you have tried yet.

Comment: The thing is I am totally new to the concept of a observer page. I have no idea where to even begin

Comment: Can you edit into your question an example of an asynchronous call that you might make, and why you would make it? I take it this is JavaScript? (Hmm, I wonder if you mean a web service in PHP where it kicks off a remote job on a queue? If so, a status call should be provided by your API - maybe you can call that on a cron to see the condition of async processes? Again I am guessing here, because of the limited information supplied).

Comment: Hi Halfer, I think the asynchronous is confusing. The reason it is asynchronous is that I have one PHP page calling a web service which is starts a monitor and on a specific event, another PHP page is called by the web service server. So, I need to have a PHP page that can consume or process the response from the web service server